# Javascript, jQuery element selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't understand what this selector selects actually:

```
var x=$("a[href*='y']")
```

Could you guys explain it me in plain English.

Thanx in advance
Dhiaa

Comment: Attribute contains selector https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Comment: Description: Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value containing a given substring.

Answer (score 2):

`*=` means contains, so in this case it is selecting all anchor (`a`) tags that contain `y`

See [documentation on jquery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) here.

Answer (score 2):

`a[href*='y']` matches any elements that:

1. Are `a` elements, **and**
2. Have an `href` attribute that *contains* `y` (`[attr*=...]` is an attribute 'contains' substring selector; [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings), [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/))

Answer (score 0):

This selector selects an  with attribute, contains href='y'.
That means that you select some link () which leads (href) to y

Read more about jq attributes here https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Answer (score 0):

It selects every  element whose href attribute value contains “y”.